# Php Dynamic Table Showing Server Date/Time Format

Tags: php, datetime, dynamic

I have Created the Program where I am Fetching the Content from a text file from a cpanel server,
In my Table Fields It shows the Date Format in Server format i.e (YYYY/MM/DD) I want it to Display as
(DD/MM/YYYY).
This is My Code

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("file-path.txt");
    $arr = explode(";", $data);
    echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">";
                echo "<th style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">Doctor Name</th>";
                echo "<th style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">Leave From (YYYY/MM/DD)</th>";
                echo "<th style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">Leave To (YYYY/MM/DD)</th>";
                echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">Remarks</th>';
                echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
            for($value = 0; $value < count($arr)-1; $value=$value+4) {
                echo "<tr style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">";
                echo "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">".$arr[$value]."</td>";
                echo "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">".$arr[$value+1]."</td>";
                echo "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">".$arr[$value+2]."</td>";
                echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$arr[$value+3].'</td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: I need to change the Date Format from this (YYYY/MM/DD) to (DD/MM/YYYY).It is displaying Server Format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use date_format() function bro
date_format($arr[$value+2],"d/m/Y");

Answer (score 0):

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($arr[$value+2]));
```

Have a try, you can do it.